# Complex SQL Query with Dead Ends and 7 Tables

Tags: sql

I was tasked with creating a complex query that incudes all of the data from all of the tables minus the Keys. I am having an issue with the dead end tables and how to circle back around to include the data of the connecting table. I need to select columns DivisionName, ProgramName, ProgramChairFName, ProgramChairLName, CourseID, OutcomeDescription from the listed tables.

[SQL Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSMr5.jpg)
[image]

Comment: What have you tried with the query? Is there any reason a long series of JOINs won't work?

Comment: How do I backout of a deadend like

Comment: select DivisionName, PR.ProgramName,CourseID, ProgramChairFName, ProgramChairLName, Outcomedescription
from Outcome
join CourseOutcome
on outcome.OutcomeKey = CourseOutcome.OutcomeKey
Join Course
on CourseOutcome.CourseKey = course.CourseKey
join Program AS PR
on course.ProgramKey = PR.ProgramKey
join Division
on PR.DivisionKey = Division.DivisionKey
join Program
on Division.DivisionKey = Program.DivisionKey
Join ProgramChairMap
on Program.ProgramKey = ProgramChairMap.ProgramKey
Join ProgramChair
on ProgramChairMap.ProgramChairKey = ProgramChair.ProgramChairKey;

Comment: see answer below

Answer (score 0):

The 'dead-ends' aren't really dead-ends. When you join all the tables by the appropriate keys, you'll get an assembly of the information you want.

Consider a really simple example:

```
table person
id    name
 1    Alice

table pet
id    person_id    animal
 1    1            cat

table hobby
id    person_id    activity
 1    1            dancing
```

Here, the two tables pet and hobby link to the person table via the person_id key.

In your thinking, "pet" could be considered a "dead-end" because it doesn't link to hobby. But it doesn't need to.  The query:

```
SELECT name, animal, activity 
FROM person
JOIN pet ON person.id = pet.person_id
JOIN hobby ON person.id = hobby.person_id;
```

creates the correct joins back to the person table. It's not a linear path (person -> pet -> hobby). The nature of the joins are specified by the "ON" part of the query.  You can see this simple example works here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02c94b/1

So, in your case, you can have a series of JOINs:

```
SELECT [all the columns you want]
FROM Division d JOIN Program p
ON d.DivisionKey = p.DivisionKey
JOIN ProgramChairMap pcm
ON p.ProgramKey = pcm.ProgramKey
JOIN ProgramChair pc
ON pcm.ProgramChairKey = pc.ProgramChairKey
JOIN Course c
ON p.ProgramKey = c.ProgramKey
JOIN CourseOutcome co
ON c.CourseKey = co.CourseKey
JOIN Outcome o
ON co.OutsomeKey = o.OutcomeKey
```